What was the name of this documentary where the author meets people sharing his name?
I've seen it about ten years ago. It's by a New York doc filmmaker I think. The premise was: he researched all (most of) the people with the same name as his own. The main piece in the film is where he invites them over, to join a meeting, to exchange their different paths through life, and "what they had done/experienced in life with 'his name'".
I think the author had a simple Christian/Jewish name, something like David Adelman, Ben Muller or Chris Birnbaum.
I think the gathering took place in Brooklyn or another suburb of New York, and a group of 30 people or so showed up.
I think it had a personal/1st-person-perspective voice over.
... It was quite good, a very unique idea, and I'd like to watch it again. Anyone here know what I'm talking about?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I didn’t watch it, but there’s Google Me from 2007.

Don't think it's what you're looking for, but a similar thing was done by British comedian Dave Gorman in his show "Are you Dave Gorman?" / "The Dave Gorman collection" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_Dave_Gorman%3F
